# In an Excel VBA macro, how can I iterate over a large number of columns?

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have the following Excel sheet and VBA macro, which replaces every `x` on columns AY, AZ, BA by the value of cell AY1, AZ1, BA1:

[image: Excel sheet]

[image: macro]

As you can see, my script has the column names hard-wired. I have many columns (approx. 300). How can I make my script automatically increase the column index by 1 / iterate over many columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()

Dim myRng, myColumn As Range

Set myRng = Range("A:C").Columns ' <- this is you range, change A:C as needed

For Each myColumn In myRng '<- this will loop through each column in your range

    myColumn.EntireColumn.Replace What:="x", Replacement:=Cells(1, myColumn.Column).Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another working method, finaly by myself:

```
Dim col As Integer

For col = 8 To 300
    Columns(col).Replace What:="x", Replacement:=Cells(1, col).Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
Next
```